# Что такое десериализация в polymer?

Tags: javascript

То ли слабый английский, то ли что. Объясните, что такое **десереализация**?

> If a property is configured in the properties object, an attribute on
>   the instance matching the property name will be deserialized according
>   to the type specified and assigned to a property of the same name on
>   the element instance.
>
> If no other properties options are specified for a property, the type
>   (specified using the type constructor, e.g. Object, String, etc.) can
>   be set directly as the value of the property in the properties object;
>   otherwise it should be provided as the value to the type key in the
>   properties configuration object.
>
> The type system includes support for Boolean and Number values, Object
>   and Array values expressed as JSON, or Date objects expressed as any
>   Date-parsable string representation.
>
> Boolean properties are set based on the presence of the attribute: if
>   the attribute exists at all, the property is set to true, regardless
>   of the attribute value. If the attribute is absent, the property gets
>   its default value.

Answer (score 1):

**Сериализация** - это когда объект(как программная сущность) переводится в текстовый/бинарный формат, для удобства его хранения (например в БД) и/или передачи (например в виде json по http)

**Десериализация** - наоборот, восстановление из сериализованной сущности (текста/бинарного формата) исходного объекта.